# Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.1 - HTML Chart - Multi value Parameter

Tags: html, charts, jasper-reports

I've designed the HTML chart using the oracle query which passes single value parameter and it worked fine. I used the method of placing the `HTML Chart` in the `Summary band` and set the `Evalution time` to `Now` and it worked fine.

Now I would like to show the same `HTML chart` using multi value Parameter. I would like to show the chart element for each project in each pdf page. Hence logically I need to place the `HTML chart` at `Detail band` rather than the `Summary band`. But now it doesn't work and throws error "incrementing bidimensional dataset"

FYI, I'm using this Chart report as subreport to another main report.

Jaspersoft studio version:5.6.1 final

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Charts" pageWidth="200" pageHeight="275" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="200" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="c6523df6-0c5f-4728-87c2-57825f88fca3">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="inch" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel" />
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Dev DB Conn" />
<parameter name="param_month" class="java.lang.String" />
<parameter name="param_year" class="java.lang.String" />
<parameter name="param_project" class="java.util.Collection" />
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT
            i.id prid,c.INUSAGE,d.CURRUSAGE
            FROM
            project table i, custom table c
            where i.id = c.id and $X{IN,I.id,param_project}
            ]]>
</queryString>
<field name="prid" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<field name="INUSAGE" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<field name="CURRUSAGE" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<summary>
    <band height="223">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="3" width="190" height="220" uuid="0a0e6b98-2d59-453a-8642-3a65d4b30bb1">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="inch" />
            </reportElement>
            <hc:chart xmlns:hc="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jaspersoft.com/highcharts http://jaspersoft.com/schema/highcharts.xsd" type="Column" evaluationGroup="">
                <hc:chartSetting name="default">
                    <hc:chartProperty name="_showDataPoints">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="_showMeasureNameOnValueAxis">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.alignTicks">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.animation">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.borderRadius">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.borderWidth">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.ignoreHiddenSeries">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.selectionMarkerFill">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new java.awt.Color(-1)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.shadow">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.spacingBottom">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(20)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="chart.zoomType">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["none"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="colors">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[java.util.Arrays.asList("#779499","#C0D9DE","#8bbc21","#910000","#1aadce","#492970","#f28f43","#77a1e5","#c42525","#a6c96a","#C0D9DE")]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="credits.enabled">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[false]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="credits.href">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[""]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="credits.text">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[""]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.align">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["center"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.borderRadius">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(5)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.enabled">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.floating">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.layout">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["horizontal"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.lineHeight">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(30)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.margin">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(15)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.padding">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(8)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.symbolPadding">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(5)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.symbolWidth">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(30)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.verticalAlign">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["bottom"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.x">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(10)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legend.y">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(10)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="legened.itemStyle.fontSize" value="4" />
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.animation">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled" value="true" />
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format" value="{point.y:,.0f}" />
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.lineWidth">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(2)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.shadow">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.showInLegend">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.series.visible">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="title.align">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["left"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="title.style.color">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new java.awt.Color(-4138530)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="title.text">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[""]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="title.verticalAlign">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA["top"]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="tooltip.animation">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="tooltip.enabled">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="tooltip.shadow">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="xAxis.labels.step">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[new Integer(0)]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="yAxis.gridLineColor" value="'#FFFFFF'" />
                    <hc:chartProperty name="plotOptions.column.marker.enabled">
                        <hc:propertyExpression>
                            <![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]>
                        </hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
                    <hc:chartProperty name="yAxis.title.text" value="" />
                </hc:chartSetting>
                <multiAxisData>
                    <multiAxisDataset />
                    <dataAxis axis="Rows">
                        <axisLevel name="InvName">
                            <labelExpression>
                                <![CDATA[]]>
                            </labelExpression>
                            <axisLevelBucket class="java.lang.String">
                                <bucketExpression>
                                    <![CDATA[]]>
                                </bucketExpression>
                            </axisLevelBucket>
                        </axisLevel>
                    </dataAxis>
                    <dataAxis axis="Columns" />
                    <multiAxisMeasure name="Initial Baseline" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Highest">
                        <labelExpression>
                            <![CDATA["Initial Baseline"]]>
                        </labelExpression>
                        <valueExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{INUSAGE}]]>
                        </valueExpression>
                    </multiAxisMeasure>
                    <multiAxisMeasure name="Current Baseline" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Highest">
                        <labelExpression>
                            <![CDATA["Current Baseline"]]>
                        </labelExpression>
                        <valueExpression>
                            <![CDATA[$F{CURRUSAGE}]]>
                        </valueExpression>
                    </multiAxisMeasure>
                </multiAxisData>
                <hc:series name="Current Baseline" />
                <hc:series name="Initial Baseline" />
            </hc:chart>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Thanks

Comment: `Hence Logically I need to place the HTML chart at Detail band.` Not true. If you simply want to add "more lines to a line chart", this does not depend on the Detail band but on your SQL and the configuration of the element.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.I want to have the bar chart for each project displayed in each pdf page. Hence I'm trying to put the chart in the detail band which will get me this result. Am I doing something wrong here? Also I've added the code $X{IN,tablecolumn,param_name} in the query to get the results. Results are working fine for all text and static results. only chart is having the issue. Please do provide any workaround

Comment: SO is no service, but a community. Please refrain from asking "help ASAP" and "provide any workaround". This is what we want to do if it is possible to understand the case. Because of that: Please [edit] your question, add jrxml and screenshots about the behaviour.

Comment: I've added the jrxml code for the HTML Chart which is included in the summary band. When I move the chart from Sumamry to detail or Group header, it throws the error "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error incrementing bidimensional dataset"

Comment: Have you seen [this topic about the problem](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/801726/how-use-html5-charts)?

Comment: Thanks Tobi, I tried these method too. 1) I changed evaluation time to report and then created a group with 0 inch. Kept the chart in summary band - the chart didn't iterate 2) moved the chart to Group header and removed summary. Kept the evaluation time to report and increment type to Group-chart  iterated 16 times for onlyone project,even though I gave two projects as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. The iterations was due to the query issue. To solve the chart issue, I placed the Chart in the group header and then I chnaged the evalution time to Column and then changed the reset type in the chart to Page. Now I could able to get the chart for each project in each page. Hope this helps someone later. Cheers