# Jasper -Java.util.collection paramter from main to Sub report

Tags: collections, jasper-reports, subreport

I've chart report which uses the parameter of Type Java.util.collection. When I try to use this chart  at group band as subreport to the Main report with similar parameter of Type Java.util.collection, the chart value keep iterates within the group. For example, if the chart shows the value for L1 & L2 in two separate page. But when added to the Main report for the value L1, the subreport displays both L1 & L2 rather than just L1.

Could I able to display just L1 from subreport when the parameter is passed as L1, not both L& L2 in the group band?

FYI, using Jaspersoft Studio 5.6.1

**EDIT:**

Suppose I am passing 2 Projects P1 and P2 as parameters from main report, the result now I am getting is:

- 1st page Main report data P1
- Sub report data P1
- Sub report data P2
- 2nd page Main report Data P2
- Sub report data P1
- Sub report data P2

But, the desired result should be like this:

- 1st page Main report data P1
- Sub report data P1
- 2nd page Main report Data P2
- Sub report data P2.

I've added the subreport in one of the Group header.

Main Report:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d2616041-39f3-44ce-a1e4-4ce5a6a1593c">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Dev DB Conn" />
<parameter name="param_project" class="java.util.collection" nestedType="java.lang.Integer">
    <parameterDescription>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </parameterDescription>
</parameter>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT
                i.id prid,c.INUSAGE,d.CURRUSAGE
                FROM
                project table i, custom table c
                where i.id = c.id and $X{IN,I.id,param_project}
                ]]>
</queryString>
<field name="prid" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<field name="INUSAGE" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<field name="CURRUSAGE" class="java.math.BigDecimal" />
<group name="Group1">
    <groupExpression>
        <![CDATA[$F{INVID}]]>
    </groupExpression>
</group>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="210">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="80" height="30" uuid="263d8d17-1c40-4709-ba8f-76e27a976c75" />
            <textFieldExpression>
                <![CDATA[$F{prid}]]>
            </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="80" y="2" width="200" height="200" uuid="da630714-b937-493c-9db5-a4baa7128f3d" />
            <subreportParameter name="param_invID">
                <subreportParameterExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{param_project}]]>
                </subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression>
                <![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]>
            </connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression>
                <![CDATA["Workload1_added_collection_group1.jasper"]]>
            </subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
```

Subreport link: [subreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524223/jaspersoft-studio-5-6-1-html-chart-multi-value-parameter)

Thanks

Sreeram

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `jrxml` information as well as screenshots if possible. What is the way you want it? Where in the main report did you put it?

Comment: Tobi, updated the question. Added the jrxml. Suppose I am passing 2 Projects P1 and P2 as parameters from main report, the result now I am getting is,

1st page

Main report data P1, Sub report data P1, Sub report data P2

2nd page

Main report Data P2, Sub report data P1, Sub report data P2

But, the desired result should be like this,

1st page

Main report data P1, Sub report data P1

2nd page

Main report Data P2, Sub report data P2.I've added the subreport in one of the Group header.

Comment: Does this have to do with the subreport? Usually the subreport should only get the item it should display, e.g. "P1 ID" for P1 and "P2 ID" for P2. But if you provide a collection it will *always* cycle through the collection of data.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, I added the chart directly to the mainreport, it worked. Now I've another issue. I've two subreports on main reports. For the multi value parameter input(Type:Collection), the first subreport should follow the second report  for the first input and for the second input, again first subreport should follow the second subreport. But in my case, it prints all the value of first sureport and then it prints all the values of Second subreport. How could I make it a proper report? Is this a placement problem because I placed the subreports in Group header

Comment: No problem. Please open a new question with your description in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the subreport should only get the item it should display, e.g. "P1 ID" for P1 and "P2 ID" for P2. But if you provide a collection it will always cycle through the collection of data.

So you should add either the ID to the subreport or put the chart in the main report.